# Livecode- scrolling a datagrid (with last offset)

Tags: scroll, datagrid, livecode

I have created a scroller control for my datagrid with the following code:

```
function scroller_create tPoint
   local tScrollerRect, tContentRect
   if environment() is not "mobile" then exit scroller_create

   put the rect of group "list" into tScrollerRect
   put 0,0,(the DGformattedWidth of group "list"),(the DGformattedHeight of group "list") into tContentRect

   mobileControlCreate "scroller", "listScroll"
   put the result into sScrollerID

   mobileControlSet "listScroll", "rect", tScrollerRect
   mobileControlSet "listScroll", "contentRect", tContentRect
   mobileControlSet "listScroll", "visible", true
   mobileControlSet "listScroll", "scrollingEnabled", true
   mobileControlSet "listScroll", "vIndicator", true
   mobileControlSet "listScroll", "vScroll", tPoint
end scroller_create
```

When more data is added into the datagrid, I will destroy and recreate the scroller control. But I wanted to make the scroller to stay on the last vertical scroll offset (tPoint).

But with ***mobileControlSet "listScroll", "vScroll", tPoint*** it will still reset the vertical scroller back to the top when the scroller is recreated...

Is there any other way where I can fix the vscroll of the datagrid on last offset?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the **contenctRect**?
However store the **vscroll**  in a custom property using **mobileControlGet** and set it again.

Comment: Hi MaxV, thanks for the comment. I've managed to set the DGVscroll to display the list, but as soon as I touch the phone screen (and slide), the list will go up to the top most again before sliding down... 

Using the native vScrollBar will not cause this issue. It's weird... still trying to figure out a way to solve this.

Thanks!